# How can I pass my in's in a MySQL stored procedure as the column titles?

Tags: mysql

In this stored procedure let's use these for the example:

- `varReportYear1` = `'2018'`
- `varReportYear2` = `'2019'`

I want those two years to be the column titles in this pivot table.
In the SELECT you can see I've added `AS '2018'` and `AS '2019'`, but ideally these would equal the incoming values.

Any help is very appreciated -- thank you!.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`me`@`%` PROCEDURE `spPivotReport`(
    in varReportYear1 char(4),
    in varReportYear2 char(4)
)
BEGIN
/*
* I want to have the values for 
* varReportYear1 and varReportYear2
* set as column headers
* in this pivot table.
*/

SELECT 
    `query_for_pivot`.`school` AS varschool,
    COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = varReportYear1),
        `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
        NULL)) AS '2018',
    COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = varReportYear2),
        `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
        NULL)) AS '2019'
FROM
    `query_for_pivot`
WHERE
    `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = varReportYear1
        OR `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = varReportYear2
GROUP BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`
ORDER BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`
;
END
```

Comment: You'll need to use the [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to form your query with those column titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY... WITH a little help I was able to answer my own question. Thank you to everyone who answered.

This answer has been tested in MySQL 5.6.12 and 8.0.14. To come up with a working stored procedure, I modified @GMB's answer.

#### What did I change from GMB's sp? (see below)

1. For the column headers, I had to concatenate *yr_* to the variable value. It did not like the digit-only column headers (varReportYear1='2018', varReportYear2='2019' in my example).
2. I had to put single quotes around the variables.

**Here's my working code:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spPivotReportPrepared`(
in varReportYear1 char(4),
in varReportYear2 char(4)
)
BEGIN

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT 
        `query_for_pivot`.`school` AS varschool,
        COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ',varReportYear1,'),
            `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
            NULL)) AS yr_',varReportYear1, ',
        COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ',varReportYear2,'),
            `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
            NULL)) AS yr_',varReportYear2,'
    FROM
        `query_for_pivot`
    WHERE
        `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ',varReportYear1,'
            OR `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ',varReportYear2,'
    GROUP BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`
    ORDER BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`');
    

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Good point for searching by yourself and posting the answer ! +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

you can use prepared statements. see below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`me`@`%` PROCEDURE `spPivotReport`(
    in varReportYear1 char(4),
    in varReportYear2 char(4)
)
BEGIN
   PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT 
        `query_for_pivot`.`school` AS varschool,
        COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ?),
            `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
            NULL)) AS ?,
        COUNT(IF((`query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ?),
            `query_for_pivot`.`request_id`,
            NULL)) AS ?
    FROM
        `query_for_pivot`
    WHERE
        `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ?
            OR `query_for_pivot`.`year_of_request` = ?
    GROUP BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`
    ORDER BY `query_for_pivot`.`school`';

    EXECUTE stmt1 USING 
      varReportYear1 , 
      varReportYear1, 
      varReportYear2,
      varReportYear2,
      varReportYear1,
      varReportYear2 ;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END;
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6 and 8.0. Neither one would let me apply this stored procedure. The trouble seems to be with the EXECUTE stmt1 USING section. The list of variables has red x-marks and red-squiggly underlines indicating error. Plus, a DDL error message pops up when I click "Apply" in MySQL Workbench when I try to apply this sp.